# VS2013 - Output window does not show std::cout

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I am developing an unmanaged C++11 application and debugging it in VS2013. I have a helper class

```
#include <cstdio>
class DebugHelper : public dbg::IDebugHelper {
   public:
     virtual void outputLine(const std::string & message) const override 
     { std::cout << message << std::endl; }
   .....
 };
```

I expected that string printed via outputLine of DebugHelper would show in the studio Output window. However this is not happening neither for std::cout nor for std::err. Is it supposed to? Is there a setting of some sort in project properties that I am missing? BTW the same code works as expected on Mac  under QtCreator.

Comment: A line of code from a class doesn't really prove you're outputting anything. Show us the program that demonstrates the issue. Edit: If it's the debug window, then you need to use `OutputDebugString` or the `TRACE` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Visual Studio, use `OutputDebugString` or `TRACE` to output to the debug monitor (which is the `Output` window when running in Visual Studio).

IMO using the aforementioned functions to output strings for debugging purposes is preferred to `cout`, and the awful "MessageBox" approach, since both of these other approaches could (and many times, will) interfere with the operation of the program that you're running.

Comment: Thank you. I have my doubts regarding TRACE because I need the output both in debug and release builds. However OutputDebugString does what I need and works for in debug and release.

Comment: @LRaiz - I also prefer OutputDebugString -- just added `TRACE` just in case you ran into it.

Answer (score 2):

The output windows shows content from the Debug stream - the console output goes to the console window.

Comment: more specifically, cout is redirected to standard out, which is the  console window by default.  Could be sent to other locations (i.e. file).